# Count of rows based on the value of the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This is an example of the table:

[image: Link to Image of table]

Based on that table I need to create a query that brings something like this as result,

[image: Link to example of results]

I will have 1 row for each ProductID and N quantity of columns with the count of Reworks before it breaks, if the product broke 10 times then I will see 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to count the number of breaks up to each row.  Then just use conditional aggregation:

```
select productid, creationdate,
       sum(case when statustype = 'rework' and num_breaks = 0
                then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt_before_first_break,
       sum(case when statustype = 'rework' and num_breaks = 1
                then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt_before_second_break
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when stationtype = 'break' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by productid, creationdate
                  order by status_timestamp
                 ) as num_breaks
      from t
     ) t
group by productid, creationdate;
```

Comment: The name of this method is Windows Function?

Comment: @TheOA . . . The subquery has a window function.  It has the `over` clause.

Comment: I see, I will do the research, I tried the query and yeah it is working for the ProductID that only broke 2 times if they broke 3-4-5 times I am trying to get a solution, but this is helping a lot

Answer (score 0):

since you only require 2 levels of count, you can consider this query.

```
with cte as (

select '201207' as ProductId, '2019-10-01' as CreationDate, 'Rework' as StationDesc, '2019-09-01' as status_timestamp
    union all 
    select '201207', '2019-10-01', 'Rework', '2019-09-02' 
    union all
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Rework', '2019-09-03' 
    union all 
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Break', '2019-09-04' 
    union all
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Rework',  '2019-09-05' 
    union all 
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Rework', '2019-09-06' 
    union all
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Break', '2019-09-07' 
    union all 
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Rework', '2019-09-08' 
    union all
    select '201207', '2019-10-01','Break', '2019-09-09' 
) 
select 
    ProductId,
    CreationDate,
    sum(case when status_timestamp < d1
        and StationDesc = 'Rework' then 1 else 0 end) as FirstBreak,
    sum(case when status_timestamp between d1 and d2 
        and StationDesc = 'Rework' then 1 else 0 end) as SecondBreak
from cte
cross join
    (select t1.status_timestamp as d1, t2.status_timestamp as d2 from
        (select row_number() over (partition by ProductId,CreationDate order by status_timestamp) as rn
            , status_timestamp from cte where StationDesc = 'Break') as t1
    left join
        (select row_number() over (partition by ProductId,CreationDate order by status_timestamp) as rn
            , status_timestamp from cte where StationDesc = 'Break') as t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
    where t1.rn < 2) as t3
group by ProductId,
    CreationDate
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: For the cases with only 2 breaks works, but if you want to run it to analyze a large table that have other ProductId that break 3...4...5 or more times, anyway this is helping a lot to get closer for what I'm looking to create